# Help Needed To Prove A Trigonometric Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I'am trying to prove the below identity, but this is what i end up getting. $$\begin{align*}
\frac{2\tan(x)}{1 + \tan^2(x)} &= \sin(2x)\\
&= \frac{2\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{1 + \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}\\
&= 2\sin(x)
\end{align*}$$

Can someone point out the mistake for me please?

Comment: $\frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos x} = \cos x \neq 1$ for general $x$.

Comment: Your last step went wrong. It should be $\frac{2\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{1 + \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}} = 2\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{{\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}} = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(2x)$  Using the fact that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{2\tan(x)}{1 + \tan^2(x)} = \frac{2\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{1 + \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}= 2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $1=\frac{cos^2(x)}{cos^2(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

after solving the middle step, you will end up as 1/cos^2(x) as denominator. After dividing, it becomes 2*sin(x)*cos(x) which is equal to sin(2x).